# Error when mounting ntfs disk after crash

Tags: mount, kubuntu, hard-drive, ntfs, udisks

I ran `rdfind` on my backup disk, causing my system to freeze. After a forced restart, the disk showed 0 bytes in partition manager. I managed to mount it in Windows, and then the bytes used got fixed in Linux. However, I can't mount it using Dolphin or `udisksctl` in Linux. When attempting to mount with Dolphin, I get the error:

`Error mounting /dev/sdb1: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Error.Failed: Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/harry/Elements: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error`

However, I can mount it successfully using the mount command.

Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I plugged it into a windows 11 computer and it asked to repair it, afterwards it works fine in linux. :/